# How to pick elements from a list with variable condition

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, sets

Let `A` and `M` sets of numbers, with `Length[A]=15`. I want to do something like

```
Pick[M, #+A[[1]] <= 1 & /@ M]
```

but, instead of testing only with $i=1$, testing with all $i\in\{1,...,15\}$. I can use Pick again and again (15 times in total) to achieve the result I want, but this is not a good idea. What can I do?

EDIT1: **This is an example.** Let $M=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $A=\{-1,-2,-3,..., -15\}$. I want to get the subset $M'$ of $M$ formed by the elements $x\in M$ such that $x+y\leq 1$ for all $y\in A$, that is, $$M'= \{0,1,2\}.$$

The code have to work with any condition rather than summation, that is, it has to work with product for real number or the inner product for vectors, and so on. The problem here is that `#+A[[i]]` test the condition "$\leq 1$" with only one element of A (the $i$-nth), and I want to test with all of them.

EDIT2: **This is my true motivation.** Let

```
M={{0, 0, 0, 1}, {-(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2, 1/2}, {-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2}, {-(1/2), 1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, {-(1/2), 1/2, -(1/2), 1/2}, {1/2, -(1/2), 1/2, 1/2}, {-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1,0}, {1/2, -(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, -(1/2), 1/2}, {0, -1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2)}, {-(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2, -(1/2)}, {-(1/2), 1/2, 1/2, -(1/2)}, {1/2, 1/2, 1/2, -(1/2)}, {-(1/2), 1/2, -(1/2), -(1/2)}, {1/2, -(1/2), 1/2, -(1/2)}, {1/2, -(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2)}, {1/2, 1/2, -(1/2), -(1/2)}, {0, 0, 0, -1}}
```

and

```
A={{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1, 1}, {-1, -1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1, 1}}.
```

I aim to obtain as output the subset $$M'=\{v\in M~;~|\langle v,w \rangle|\leq 1, \forall~ w\in A\}.$$
With `Pick[M, Abs[#.A[[1]]] <= 1 & /@ M]` I get the set $$M'_0=\{v\in M~;~|\langle v,w_1 \rangle|\leq 1\},$$ where `w1=A[[1]]`. I could use Pick again like

```
Pick[Pick[M, #+A[[1]] <= 1 & /@ M],#+A[[2]] <= 1 & /@Pick[M, #+A[[1]] <= 1 & /@ M]]
```

and get $$M'_1=M'_0\cap\{v\in M~;~|\langle v,w_2 \rangle|\leq 1\},$$ where `w2=A[[2]]`. I am looking for a smarter way to obtain $M'$.

I just realize that using `Table[Select[M, # + A[[k]] <= 1 &], {k, Length[A]}]` and then `Flatten` and then `DeleteDuplicates` is not a solution. As above, we have to make intersections, and this is an union.

Comment: Why it's not a good idea? You can calculate selectors in one go and map over them with `Pick[M, #] & /@ Outer[#1 + #2 <= 1 &, M, A]`

Comment: What I said is not a good idea is use something like `Pick[Pick[M, #+A[[1]] <= 1 & /@ M],#+A[[2]] <= 1 & /@Pick[M, #+A[[1]] <= 1 & /@ M]]`. I am new on Mathematica. Could you please elaborate your idea?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, can you provide an example of what you need? Does `Pick[M, Or @@@ Outer[#1 + #2 <= 1 &, M, A]]` returns what you need?

Comment: I think an example input with the correct output would be helpful here, along with an explanation of what is intended.

Comment: `Select[m, AllTrue[# + a, # <= 1 &] &]`

Comment: @Pillsy I edited the post. I had a problem with your code. `Select[m, AllTrue[Abs[#.A], # <= 1 &] &]` is returning the empty set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
Pick[M, LessEqualThan[1] /@ Max /@ Abs[M.Transpose[A]]]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 1}, {-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2}, {-(1/2), 1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, {1/
>     2, -(1/2), 1/2, 1/2}, {-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {1/2, 1/2, -(1/2), 1/
>     2}, {0, -1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 
>     0}, {-(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2, -(1/2)}, {1/2, 1/2, 1/2, -(1/2)}, {-(1/2), 1/
>     2, -(1/2), -(1/2)}, {1/2, -(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2)}, {0, 0, 0, -1}}

Answer (score 2):

For the version of the question before Edit 2:

```
m = Range[0, 5];
a = -Range[15];
Pick[m, NonPositive[Max[# + a - 1] & /@ m]]
(* or Select[m, NonPositive[Max[# + a - 1]]&] *)
```

> {0, 1, 2}

**Update:** For the general case, with `M` and `A` as in OP's Edit 2, simply change `# + a -1` to `#.Transpose[A] - 1`:

```
Pick[M, NonPositive[Max[#.Transpose[A] - 1]& /@ M]]
Pick[M, UnitStep[1 - Max[#.Transpose[A]]] & /@ M, 1] 
Select[M, NonPositive[Max[#.Transpose[A] - 1]]&]
```

all give

> {{0,0,0,1}, {-(1/2),-(1/2),-(1/2),1/2}, {-(1/2),1/2,1/2,1/2}, {1/2,-(1/2),1/2,1/2}, <<9>>, {-(1/2),1/2,-(1/2),-(1/2)}, {1/2,-(1/2),-(1/2),-(1/2)}, {0,0,0,-1}}

Comment: Please take a look at my edited post

Comment: @Filburt, that edit changes everything:)

Answer (score 2):

```
Pick[M,Max /@ Outer[Abs[#1. #2] &, M, A, 1],1]
```

yields:

```
{{0, 0, 0, 1}, {-(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2}, {-(1/2), 1/2, 1/2, 1/
  2}, {1/2, -(1/2), 1/2, 1/2}, {-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {1/2, 1/
  2, -(1/2), 1/2}, {0, -1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 
  0, 0}, {-(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2, -(1/2)}, {1/2, 1/2, 1/
  2, -(1/2)}, {-(1/2), 1/2, -(1/2), -(1/2)}, {1/
  2, -(1/2), -(1/2), -(1/2)}, {0, 0, 0, -1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is use `Dot` to take the inner product with all the elements of `A` at once, which makes it relatively easy to use `Select` and `AllTrue`:

```
Select[M, AllTrue[A.#, Abs[#] <= 1 &] &]
```